# Scala future strange error on completion

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I am just getting started with futures and stumbled upon an error which seems quite strange to me:

Using play-ws to perform a post request and map the result:

```
wsClient.url(url).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json")
      .post(payload)
      .map { wsResponse =>
        if (!(200 to 299).contains(wsResponse.status)) {
          sys.error(s"Received unexpected status, open-cpu error ${wsResponse.status} : ${wsResponse.body}")
        }
        println(s"OK, received ${wsResponse.body}")

        wsResponse.json.validate[Seq[MyClass]] match {
          case JsSuccess(result, _) => result.map(outlierRes => Map("key" -> outlierRes.attr, "key2" -> outlierRes.attr2, "key3" -> outlierRes.val3))
          case JsError(error) => throw new MyException(error.toString())
        }
      }
```

works just fine. The println of the body shows everything is there, and the validation succeeds.

The problem lies here: aggregatedData = `Await.result(theFutureFromAbove, 20.minutes)`

This statement crashes with the following when run via the interactive console:

```
MyException
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
        at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
        at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Which would suggest a parsing exception.

However, when run via `sbt run` there is a different exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Which resembles this line:     `wsClient.url(baseUrl + url).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json")`

## edit

It seems to be triggered by: `wsClient.close()` as if I closed the wsClient before the future completed. 
However, in the documentation it states

> If you create a WSClient manually then you must call client.close() to
>   clean it up when you’ve finished with it.

so where should I close it? Initially, I thought it would be safe to close after the `Await.result` but that still is throwing the error.

## edit 2

```
wsResponse.json.validate[Seq[MyClass]].fold(
          error => {
            println(error)
            Future.failed(new MyException("parsing failed" + error))
          },
          result => result.map(data => Map("period" -> data.period, "amount" -> data.totalAmount, "outlier" -> data.isOutlier))
        )
```

But this still does not compile as `Future[nothing]` does not match my return type of `Future[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]`

Comment: In a Play app (not when using WS as standalone lib) you should never close the client, which is provided by the DI context, and released accordingly. P.S Using `sys.error` in a `Future.map`, mixed with `JsResult` is not optimal/clear for me. Better to `flatMap` and have either successful nested `Future` or `Future.failed`.

Comment: I have to admit it is not a play app. Just standalone ws. Regarding your tip: I am just getting started with futures. How would I produce a Future.failed? Is it created automatically e.g. in the match-case I would only need to match the success case? So I would handle the failure like: ```val result = performRequest(someData)
    result.onFailure{
      case t => throw new MyException(t.getMessage)
    }```

Comment: `onFailure`/`onSuccess`/`onComplete` are side-effect callback and should not be used to `map` a `Future` result. `Future.failed` just take an `Exception` instance.If you intend to close the `WSClient` after the `Future` (not optimal), you can use `andThen`. Please have a look at the `Future` scaladoc.

Comment: Ok - but a `case JsError(error) => Future.failed(new Exception("Mapping Error", error))` doesn't work because my function should have the following return tye: `Future[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]`

Comment: You seems to misunderstand how it works. There is a phantom type there: `Future.failed[T](exception)`

Comment: Is a solution like this one https://github.com/studiodev/Mocky/blob/master/app/services/GithubRepository.scala a good example how to deal with errors in Future's ?

Comment: @cchantep please see edit 2

Comment: You are still mixing types. The error and success should both be represented as successful or failed `Future[T]`, using either `.failed[T](exce)` or `Future { ... }` (or `.successful[T]`), with `T` the type of async value.The JSON validation,either `JsError` or `JsSuccess` should also be turned as `Future` so it can be composed.Have a look at the various `Future` examples around the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/studiodev/Mocky/blob/master/app/services/GithubRepository.scala I finally found something similar to

```
private def parseGistResponse(response: WSResponse): Future[GistResponse] = {
    if (response.status < 400) {
      logger.debug(s"<< (${response.status}) ${response.body}")
      response.json.validate[GistResponse].fold(
        error => {
          logger.error(s"Unable to parse GistResponse: $error")
          Future.failed(new RuntimeException("parse-json-failed"))
        },
        gistResponse => Future.successful(gistResponse))
    } else {
      logger.error("Unable to parse GitResponse, cannot contact WS\n" + debugResponse(response))
      Future.failed(new RuntimeException("ws-error"))
    }
  }
```